# Не компилируется maven проект. Как отследить где ошибка?

Tags: java, maven, java-8

Как найти ошибку?

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/exporter_importer -Dmaven.home=/home/dubravsky/idea-IU-182.4892.20/plugins/maven/lib/maven3 -Dclassworlds.conf=/home/dubravsky/idea-IU-182.4892.20/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf -javaagent:/home/dubravsky/idea-IU-182.4892.20/lib/idea_rt.jar=42859:/home/dubravsky/idea-IU-182.4892.20/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/dubravsky/idea-IU-182.4892.20/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.2.5 clean validate compile test package verify install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building exporter_importer 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ exporter_importer ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/exporter_importer/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ exporter_importer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ exporter_importer ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 40 source files to /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/exporter_importer/target/classes
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_181). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.accessClass(Lower.java:1113)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.accessSymbol(Lower.java:983)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.access(Lower.java:1220)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitIdent(Lower.java:3372)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIdent.accept(JCTree.java:2011)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2382)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.boxArgs(Lower.java:3112)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitApply(Lower.java:3015)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitExec(TreeTranslator.java:245)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCExpressionStatement.accept(JCTree.java:1296)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:162)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitBlock(Lower.java:3561)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:909)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitTry(TreeTranslator.java:218)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitTry(Lower.java:3897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCTry.accept(JCTree.java:1173)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:162)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitBlock(Lower.java:3561)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:909)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitIf(Lower.java:2977)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIf.accept(JCTree.java:1269)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:162)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitBlock(Lower.java:3561)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:909)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitWhileLoop(Lower.java:3573)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCWhileLoop.accept(JCTree.java:965)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:70)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:162)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitBlock(Lower.java:3561)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:909)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitMethodDef(TreeTranslator.java:145)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitMethodDefInternal(Lower.java:2828)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitMethodDef(Lower.java:2737)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:778)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitClassDef(Lower.java:2508)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:58)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2371)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:2390)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translateTopLevelClass(Lower.java:3932)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1512)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.desugar(JavaCompiler.java:1356)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:901)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:860)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:943)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Некоторые переменные были изменены как protected, что и дало ошибку при сборке проекта. Вернул на public и ошибка ушла.